# Caused by: org.usb4java.LoaderException: Native library not found in classpath: /org/usb4java/windows-x86/libusb-1.0.dll

Tags: java, libusb

when I ran my application I got the above error, i have *libusb-1.0.dll* file in `C:/windows/System32/` folder. but even though my application didn't find the path for *libusb-1.0.dll*. I don't know about native library. Please any one help me about this.

where should I place this dll file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 64bit OS you probably need to put it in SysWow64 folder instead (on the same level as System32). But it's probably better to just put it in the same directory as the executable.

The reason this may work is that System32 despite the name contains all the 64bit dll's and 32bit applications (that are run in comnpatibility mode) are redirected to use SysWoW64 instead (Of which mos of the dll's thunk the calls through the 64bit libraries in system32).

Comment: Have you checked your PATH variable? type "echo %PATH%" in the command line. To see if it contains System32? If not you need to add it. Right click "Computer" in the sideview of any folder and go to advanced system settings -> Environment variables button -> Select path in the system variables then add it to the variable (It's a semicolon separated list). I'm not sure if this would work, I suspect your computer wouldn't even boot if it wasn't there. But that's all I can think of!

Comment: Oh, my bad. Add it to the CLASSPATH env variable. You can just add it to the java command when you run instead if you prefer ("java something.class -cp .;C:\windows\system32", the dot is important as the something.class won't be findable itself if not). It's a bit odd to have system32 in your classpath, I find it preferable to have the dll in a libs folder next to your java executable with that classpathed, or package it inside a jar with it.

Comment: It's worth noting that the syntax for adding classpaths on the command line differs between OS's. The separator on windows is a semicolon, whilst on linux it's a colon.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put /org/usb4java/windows-x86/libusb-1.0.dll in **your project directory**

It works for me, I'm using eclipse and I put the dll in my project directory 
**src/org/usb4java/windows-x86/libusb-1.0.dll**

Comment: Where did you get the libusb-1.0.dll from? It wasn't included in the .zip file downloaded from usb4java.org?